# Does “Surfing on internet in VirtualMachine” provide privacy at work?

Tags: virtual-machine, internet, privacy

Employers can monitor all internet traffic at my work. I want some privacy while surfing with my PC which has my name and surname as username. Does surfing inside of a virtual machine installed on here provide this?

I mean at a firewall, are my surfing packets the same as or are they seen as a "Virtual Machine Packet" or something?

Answer (score 1):

No. If you access regular wbepages via HTTP then the traffic will still be sent over the network. That is true regardless if you use your work PC or a VM on your work PC.

**Only** using HTTPS sites from within the VM might help, but many websites do not offer a secure connection yet.  So mostly the answer should be: No.

I suspect that you ask the wrong question though. "Employers CAN monitor all internet traffic at my work" is true. But in most countries they are not allowed to do so without a good reason.

Answer (score 1):

No, this does not improve privacy. While, depending on the VM-software you use (and the settings therein), the VM might use a different IP- and MAC-address, which might make the connection slichtly *anonymous* (But do not rely on it!), this does **not** in improve privacy.

As Hennes stated in his answer as well, contents of any non-encryped connection can be read (and possibly changed) by all intermediate persons, e.g. employers as well as Internet Service Providers.

Using a SSL-secured connection (for websites, also known as HTTPS) prevents intermediate persons from seeing *what* you send (and receive), although it still does not prevent them from knowing *where* you connect to (as DNS-lookups, which map a name like `http://example.com` to an IP-address like `123.456.789.123` are usually not encrypted).

Better ways of ensuring privacy on the internet are:

- Use a [Virtual Private Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network). This is a system that lets you connect to another computer that can connect to the internet without being scanned. Because your connection tó the VPN is also encrypted (including the location you want the VPN to look up for you), the only thing an employer might see is that you connect to a VPN.
- Use a system like [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/), and use it well. TOR is (simply put) a system that automatically handles multiple layers of VPN-like proxies. The exact chain of proxies you use is different every time. This increased security/anonymity comes at a cost, however: Connections through TOR are a lot slower, and regularly slightly unreliable.

Note that even through you use systems like the above-stated, these protect your *transport*. What they do not protect against is how you interact with the sites.

Comment: If your work has installed their own ssl certificate on the workstation, HTTPS is no longer private.